# Chrome Opens Used Tabs on Primary Display

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I have three displays, one being the laptop display (primary), and two LED monitors. All are 1080p 60Hz. I rarely use the laptop display except as a launchpad for everything and less interacted with apps.

Regardless of whether I'm using Chrome, Brave (Chrome engine) or the new Edge (also Chrome engine), when I randomly click from one tab to another that is already in use, it sometimes jumps the current tab (the one I'm clicking into) into a new window on the laptop display. It seems to be random, but frequent enough to be 5%-10% of clicks. The new window is usually skewed to the upper left and even off the screen a little bit. It's quite bizarre and annoying.

I feel this is a bug (or display driver, aspect ratio, or multi-monitor glitch), but thought I would try here just in case. Anyone seen this issue or know the fix?

UPDATE: If I change the primary display (i.e. main monitor) to one of my LED monitors, the tab jumps to that "main" LED monitor and skewed to the upper left, just like the laptop when it was the main monitor. It also doesn't matter if it's an incognito window or not. My thought now is will it stay intact while using the browser on that primary LED monitor.

**UPDATE**: Nope, as I just clicked into this SU tab, it opened a new window on the this same monitor skewed to the upper left.

I forgot to mention, that after it pops out of the current browser window, I then I have to drag the window back over and re-dock back where it was. Is there maybe a way to disable the docking/undocking as a work around?

**UPDATE:** I have discovered that this has nothing to do with multiple monitors, other than the part where it jumps back to the primary monitor (when using multiple monitors).

However, I have recently been traveling with my other 17" beater laptop without multiple monitors and am still experiencing the issue. I have narrowed the issue down to what I believe is either being a grouped tabs issue or simply having too many tabs open.

It's also not the refresh rate as this laptop has the same 60Hz refresh rate.

I'm leaning towards grouped tabs as causing the issue because I had a ton of tabs open before I started grouping them and wasn't experiencing the issue.

**UPDATE & WORKAROUND**: The culprit is not grouped tabs. Therefore, I'm now leaning towards one of my extensions. However, it happens in Incognito window too and I'm only using two extensions there, Adguard and The Marvellous Suspender. I don't much feel like turning those off to test as this beater laptop doesn't have the memory to run all the chrome tabs I typically have open.

One workaround I've discovered is that when clicking into the tab, hold the left click longer. If you click your normal super user fast, that's when it jumps. Sometimes when I long click the left button, I can see it jump over for a split second and then come back to where it's supposed to be, but it's hard remembering to long click.

**LAST UPDATE (exactly a year later)**:

**TLDR;** I never found a solution per se. However, this issue appears to be directly related to how many tabs you have open and how powerful your GPU is.

I always have at least 50-100 grouped tabs open. I thought the issue got worse because of grouped tabs. However, grouped tabs simply allowed me to open more tabs. Even though I'm using a tab suspender to keep memory in check, it doesn't really seem to matter with this issue.

My old main laptop had a GTX980M and the issue was somewhat frequent, but more sporadic. It died two months after asking this question and I went to my older backup laptop which had a hybrid GPU setup and I disabled the AMD GPU part of the equation due to constant BSODs and the inability to find a good driver, leaving me with the severely underpowered integrated Intel chip. I also had to disable GPU rendering in all my browsers to stop the laptop from completely freezing up. It's not as bad as it sounds, although once I got the laptop stable, this issue became exponentially worse. However, I just changed my habits with my workaround above; slow clicking into the tabs and hold the left click for a second or two.

Eight months later I finally got a new laptop with an RTX 2070 and haven't seen the issue since, not once. Considering all the variables are mostly the same, it seems I was just underpowered in the GPU sense.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If all three monitors don't have the same scaling factor and same resolution, try setting them all to be the same.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, Windows 10. Yes, resolution is the same, and scaling too as far as I can tell. However, I just noticed the refresh rate on the laptop is 75Hz, whereas the monitors are 60Hz. I don't do any gaming or anything special (laptop has g-sync), so I'll look to set that to 60Hz as a test.